# Making indexes to my sql table for a query with "where" and "order by" clauses

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, sql-order-by, query-optimization

I have a table in a mysql db. My query looks like

```
SELECT device_id,date,timestamp,power,floor 
from tableData 
where date=%s 
and floor=%s 
order by timestamp desc 
limit 1
```

I have created index on my table for quicker results . My indexes:

```
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| minionData |          1 | idx1     |            1 | date        | A         |        9447 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| minionData |          1 | idx1     |            2 | floor       | A         |       12072 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

So my question is for the particular query I am using, indexes on data and floor columns are good enough or should i index on timestamp column also, for increasing the query performance?

Comment: If `%s` is substituted with some scalar values then create composite index by `(date, floor, timestamp)`. First 2 fields may be swapped if needed. For the last field DESC may be specified if the server version allows.

Comment: Only one index for each table copy may be used for optimization - all another will be ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding an index to each single column does not allow the database to properly optimize the query (only one index will be used at a time).

To start with: to optimize the `where` clause, you would need a compound index on both columns, like:

```
tableData(date, floor)
```

But to make this even more efficient, you could also add the column that is used for sorting in the ìndex, so:

```
tableData(date, floor, timestamp)
```

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can make the index descending on column `timestamp`:

```
tableData(date, floor, timestamp desc)
```

Finally: one option would be to add the other columns that you `select` in the index, to make it a *covering* index; this could allow the entire query to be executed using the index only (ie without looking at the table data):

```
tableData(date, floor, timestamp desc, device_id, power)
```

For many more information on how to optimize the use of indexes in MySQL, I would recommend reading the great [MySQL index cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) written by [Rick James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766831/rick-james) (which is also an active SO user).

Comment: Even before 8.0, `ORDER BY timestamp DESC` would be honored and performed efficiently -- by walking through the BTree backwards.  (Meanwhile, the `DESC` _in the index definition_ was ignored.)

Answer (score 1):

Adding an index to each single column doesn't guarantee database optimization, timestamp maybe used for sorting or filtering.

Just use
tableData(date, floor)